# Generate doc and redirect in browser

Tags: go

I have a binary that generates files based on input, i.e the input comes from a remote url and outputs to the file named test.pdf

I am looking to wrap this up in a Go wrapper but I can't seem to generate the pdf file and output to a new browser window, at least within the context of a Chi router Go setup, can anyone tell me where to go from here, the cmd var should call the locally installed binary (which works outside of a Go context) `/usr/local/bin/generatedoc http://localhost:8000/ test.pdf` and then output this pdf to a new browser window, i guess some kind of redirect

```
        func (config *Config) saft(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            cmd := exec.Command("/usr/local/bin/generatedoc http://localhost:8000/ test.pdf")
            fmt.Println(cmd)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Browser windows/tabs management is beyond responsibilities of HTTP protocol. On backend level (HTTP protocol) you can either push contents of generated `test.pdf` into response body of current request, or make a redirect to another request to use its response body.

In your case I think it does not make sense to do a redirect and you can use your current request.

```
func (config *Config) saft(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/local/bin/generatedoc http://localhost:8000/ test.pdf")
    fmt.Println(cmd)

    f, err := os.Open("test.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
    _, err = io.Copy(w, f)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

If you want to open response in the new tab, you would need to configure that on client level with either javascript or html. For example if you use a link:

```
<a href="/my.pdf" target="_blank">View PDF</a>
```

Comment: Do you know how to push the pdf contents in to the response body ?

Comment: Yes, that's in code snippet above. You need to `os.Open("test.pdf")` your newly created PDF file and `io.Copy(w, f)` its contents into response writer `w`.